# ksh - search for multiple strings and write lines to file

Tags: grep, ksh

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I can read code and figure it out, but I have trouble writing from scratch.

I need help starting a ksh script that would search a file for multiple strings and write each line containing one of those strings to an output file.

If I use the following command:

$ grep "search pattern" file >> output file

...that does what I want it to.  But I need to search multiple strings, and write the output in the order listed in the file.

Again... any help would be great!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the regular expression manuals. You can specify multiple strings in the search expression such as grep "John|Bill"

[Man grep](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjqko-rypLGAhVKmYAKHRQtADo&url=http%3A%2F%2Funixhelp.ed.ac.uk%2FCGI%2Fman-cgi%3Fgrep&ei=ODt_VeqWIsqyggSU2oDQAw&usg=AFQjCNH-aYCG5nK18_TzHbnXFsKHFIUwPg&sig2=ytU_tyqk51iF-KzmvH2Kcw&bvm=bv.95515949,d.eXY) will teach you a lot about regular expressions, but there are several online sites where you try them out, such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and (more colorful) [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need egrep.

```
egrep "first substring|second substring" file
```

When you have a lot substrings you can put them in a variable first

```
findalot="first substring|second substring"
findalot="${findalot}|third substring"
findalot="${findalot}|find me too"
skipsome="notme"
skipsome="${skipsome}|dirty words"
egrep "${findalot}" file | egrep -v "${skipsome}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "-f" in grep . 
Write all the strings you want to match in a file ( lets say pattern_file , the list of strings should be one per line)
and use grep like below

```
grep -f pattern_file file > output_file
```